# What's the right way to animate a view when the activity is opened?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to make an opening animation for a screen in my app. Some of the Views should have a subtle "float"-in effect, which I can do easily with a ViewPropertyAnimator.

However, I'd like for this to only happen the first time the screen is opened. If I animate it in `onCreateView`, it plays every time the screen is rotated, and I don't want that.

It seems to work as desired when I check for `savedInstanceState == null` and animate it then, but I was wondering if there's a better/different way.

Comment: When you rotate the activity is destroyed and recreated. Why should it not animate again?

Comment: so animate in onCreate not in onCreateView....and setRetainInstanceState(true) in on CreateView or in onActivityCreated....

Comment: @RohitGoswami I can't do that for two reasons. One: `setRetainInstance` breaks the back stack, and two: I can't animate the view if the view isn't created until `onCreateView`.

Comment: @Raghunandan Because I don't want it to, from a UX perspective.

Comment: store boolean value in onSaveInstanceState as true if animation done for first time and after rotation onCreate ll get called where you will check bundle's boolean value...if true dont animate otherwise animate....

Comment: Sounds like it'll be the same as `if (savedInstanceState == null)`. I was really just wondering if there's another way to do it, involving transitions or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if `savedInstanceState == null` is the correct way to handle this.

This [Google I/O 2013 talk](https://youtu.be/ihzZrS69i_s?t=20m32s) describes the technique.